# Is it posibble Development on Windows and export for iOS Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to develop one project for desktop/mobile/android/ios while searching the best option seems flutter.io but i know if you have not macos device u cannot export ios project.

I have powerfull Windows machine and macbook air, since my pc is good enough to work i would like to develop everything on my windows and while exporting moving on macbook air to export for ios devices.

Is it possible ?

Comment: possible, of course

Answer (score 0):

Its possible but few changes as Flutter UI structure is same for all Flutter Apps, but you need change and check Flutter packages path and other dependency that should support iOS also.
example
In Flutter Mobile: material package is `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`
while in Flutter Web is `import 'package:flutter_web/material.dart';`

Comment: it isnt that way now, now web support comes built in

Answer (score 0):

You could use [codemagic](https://codemagic.io/start/) if you just want to build the file for iOS. I am not sure if this it what you mean. Then you can download the iOS app file on your Macbook Air and get it on your iOS device.